# Edge extension popup does not work well with Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular-material, microsoft-edge, chromium

I'm developing an extension for Microsoft Edge. I use Angular 13 and Angular Material 13. My extension is a popup window.

When my extension opens a Material Dialog, the popup window is narrowed to 25 pixels rendering it unusable. However, when I run `ng serve` to and view my app in browser, the Material Dialog works as expected.

[image: Screenshot of Edge developer tools]

This screenshot shows that the cdk overlay container is only 25px wide.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I just use [the first example](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples) of Angular Material Dialog to test. The result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxkmx.png) which works well in Edge extension. Do you see any error under your extension in *edge://extensions/* page when you run the extension? Do you use `ng build` and use the build version in extension? How about running the build version directly in browser, does it work well?

Comment: There is [this error](https://imgur.com/a/gUhylBn)

Comment: Does this indicate a problem with my `manifest.json` or `angular.json` files?

Comment: Also tried to run `ng build` and serve the result to browser: works as expected

Comment: Do you mean the `ng build` only works in browsers not in extension? For the error, how do you apply your Angular Material theme? Besides, could you please check if you have set `body` `width` and `height` in your style which may leads to the issue.